Module federation requesting remote component from wrong origin
I'm using Module federation plugin for nextjs.
I have 2 applications. (host and calc)
When I try access the calc (http://localhost:3001) on browser, using a remote component from host (http://localhost:3000/).
The browser is requesting the source from wrong origin.


check out my 'nextjs.config.js'
const { NextFederationPlugin } = require('@module-federation/nextjs-mf');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  basePath: '/calc',
  webpack(config, options) {
    if (!options.isServer) {
      config.plugins.push(
        new NextFederationPlugin({
          name: 'calc',
          filename: 'static/chunks/remoteEntry.js',
          remotes: {
            host: `host@http://localhost:3000/v2/_next/static/chunks/remoteEntry.js`,
          },
          exposes: {},
          shared: {},
          publicpath: 'auto',
        }),
      );
    }

    return config;
  },
};



You have to set publicPath to auto in you Webpack configuration (in your calc app) so that subsequent requests made by remoteEntry.js are made from the original origin (in you case :3000).
  webpack(config, options) {
     config.output.publicPath = 'auto'


I tried with 'getPublicPath' and webpack's 'output.publicPath'.
But both failed.
https://github.com/leolima/bug-mf/commit/7f911796651e97449fe2fd366a138e692ae81f60
https://github.com/leolima/bug-mf/commit/d52485ed87d48b942ba4ca5a98a45f51522d3476

Setting config.output.publicPath = 'auto' in your host app (packages/calc/next.config.js) fixes the issue in your repo. But you are importing the Hello component in your Calc app, not the other way around. It works though. If you really want to import Calc in the Host you should be exposing the component in Calc and setting the remotes in Host (in your NextFederationPlugin in both next.config.js files)

I used calc (3001) as an example importing something from the host (3000). But the error occurs anyway because of the basePath in both applications.
Instead of downloading the resource from the absolute source, it takes it as if it were a relative url. But don't worry, I've already talked to an assiduous developer of module federation and they said that it really isn't supported yet.

If you add config.output.publicPath = 'auto' in your host app (packages/calc/next.config.js) it will work. I tested it on my machine. I will submit a PR to your repo.

i saw. Really thank you. I had tried this, but I didn't put it before the federation module

You're welcome!
